# Add 15 minute to 12 hour time format

Tags: android, datetime

I am new in android development. Converting of time format becomes too difficult from last many hours.

I need to add 15 minute given time.

I have **fromTime** = `'10:00 AM'` and **toTime** = `'02:00 PM'`. Now i need to create time slot of 15 minute between this two time. (like `10:00 AM` `10:15 AM` `10:30 AM` ... upto `02:00 PM`

I tried to add 15 minute using Calender class add methid like following way.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date d = df.parse(fromTime);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(d);
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
String newTime = df.format(calendar.getTime());
```

But it will convert `10:00 AM` to `10:15 AM`. **But, convert toTime `02:00 PM` to `02:00 AM`.** I search lot to convert but didn't find any solution.

Not even find any proper solution to create time slot.

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String fromTime = "10:00 AM";
    String toTime = "02:00 PM";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
    Date dStart = df.parse(fromTime);
    Date dEnd = df.parse(toTime);
    System.out.println(dStart);
    System.out.println(dEnd);
    Calendar calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarStart.setTime(dStart);
    while(calendarStart.getTime().before(dEnd)){
        System.out.println(calendarStart.getTime());
        calendarStart.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    }
```